# Unable to change IP address for eth0 without restart in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking, init

I have Ubuntu 12.04.1 installed.
I tried to change the IP address of the interface `eth0` in `/etc/network/interfaces` from `192.168.1.3` to `192.168.1.4`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.4
gateway 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255

sudo service networking status
```

When I issue:

```
sudo service networking restart
```

I get this response:

```
stop: Unknown instance: 
networking stop/waiting
```

And IP remains 192.168.1.3:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:33:71:cd:a4  
          inet addr:192.168.1.3  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21e:33ff:fe71:cda4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3861 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3291 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3423285 (3.4 MB)  TX bytes:521854 (521.8 KB)
          Interrupt:45 Base address:0x4000
```

Only after restart does the IP change.
Any ideas?

Comment: This may help http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/change-ubuntu-server-from-dhcp-to-a-static-ip-address/

Comment: But I don't use DHCP...

Comment: if you read the article, it doesn't require DHCP, which is disabled in the latter part..

Comment: Sorry. But any way my interfaces configured to use static IP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

`sudo ifdown eth0`
`sudo ifup eth0`

Comment: Wonderful!!! It working. But why service networking restart not working?... No ideas?...

Comment: I have no clue. I did just think those two commands could do the job.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Instead, I used `sudo ifconfig <interface name> down` and `sudo ifconfig <interface name> up`. Hopefully this helps anyone with the same issue